# Issues regarding taking input in fgets()

Tags: c, fgets

In this program the `fgets()` function is taking the previous enter as an input which is `'\n'` and hence not taking any input from the user. How to solve this issue ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char word[n + 1];
    fgets(word, n + 1, stdin);
    puts(word);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my environment, just calling `scanf("%d\n", &n);` instead consumes the newline and allows the  follow `fgets` to work correctly.

Comment: By not mixing different input methods, which all have differing behaviour. C is truly *horrible* in this respect, and gives rise to thousands of questions from people all running into similar problems. Even without that, user input requires a great deal of care and attention, sometimes more than the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Best way to solve this is to write function "read_int" which reads an entire line and parses it as integer, handling errors in the way you need errors handled (such as `puts("Bad input"); exit(1);`).

Comment: @hyde comment rewritten as:  If you find yourself "flushing buffers" or "kludging newlines" then go back one step and take a fresh approach. Consider using `fgets` for every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d", &n)` indeed stops at the first character after the number, if any. So the remaining characters typed by the user upto and including the newline are left pending in `stdin`.

You can flush this ending input with a loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int flush_input(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        flush_input(stdin);
        char word[n + 1];
        if (fgets(word, n + 1, stdin)) {
            puts(word);  // will output an extra newline
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```